# Relationships in Laravel Backpack - Not sure I understand

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I installed backpack on the latest version of Laravel 6.

Upon running this command as a test:

```
php artisan make:migration:schema create_posts_table --schema="user_id:unsignedInteger:foreign, 
name:string, slug:string, description:text, keywords:string:nullable"
```

The command created a Post model in Models/Post

I would like to see the names of the users from the "user" table in my "post" CRUD.

First question:
I generate my CRUD with:

```
php artisan backpack:crud post
```

I see the CRUD, at the top of the CRUD I would like to pass the users name from the User table in the select dropdown.

I tried this:

```
protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
$this->crud->setValidation(PostRequest::class);
// TODO: remove setFromDb() and manually define Fields
//$this->crud->setFromDb();
$this->crud->setColumnDetails([
    'label' => 'User', // Table column heading
    'type' => 'select',
    'name' => 'user_id', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
    'entity' => 'backpackuser', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    'model' => 'App\Models\backpackuser' // foreign key model
    ]);
}
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Too few arguments to function Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel::setColumnDetails(), 1 
passed in C:\laragon\www\backpack\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\PostCrudController.php on line 41 and 
exactly 2 expected
```

My problem "I think" is related to the "'entity' => 'backpackuser',"

From what I understand I need to add the relation method here but what I don't get is that Backpack did not create it when running the first command, is this normal?

Also, which model shall I user to pass the user details into a select field?
    App/User or App/Models/BackpackUser  ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[`setColumnDetails()` has two parameters](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-api#columns):

- the name/key of the column you're modifying
- the attributes you're modifying and their new values

It looks like you've only provided the second parameter. Hence the error "*Too few arguments to function `setColumnDetails()`, 1 
passed and 
exactly 2 expected*."

Try:

```php
$this->crud->setColumnDetails('user_id', [
    'label' => 'User', // Table column heading
    'type' => 'select',
    'entity' => 'backpackuser', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
]);
```

Pro tip: you don't *need* to specify the model. If on your Post model you have the backpackuser() relationship properly defined, Backpack will pick up the model from that relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should create a relationship manually and add it to the Post model.

In this case (see Users in the Posts CRUD), you need to add relation method into Post, not User.

Comment: Sorry like this?     public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }   I deleted my previous comments as I wrote the wrong model

Comment: @Benny yes exactly just add it in the Post model.

Comment: I have also setup my crud as:        `$this->crud->addColumn([
            'label' => 'User', // Table column heading
            'type' => 'select',
            'name' => 'user_id', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
            'entity' => 'user', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
            'model' => 'App\User' // foreign key model
        ]);`

Comment: It should work for the post entity, you got errors?